# A way to auto have entries in the property drawer to to track header creation and last change of the header?

Tags: org-mode

is there a way to auto have entries in the property drawer for tracking header creation and last change of the header? anyone using something like this?

Comment: Instead of a general "last change of header", which could mean a modification of any component of the header, how about using the `org-after-todo-state-change-hook`?  And, how about using the `org-insert-heading-hook` which is already included in the tail end of the function `org-insert-heading`.  You can use `M-x describe-variable` for either of the above-mentioned hooks to read more about them.

Comment: Please stop signing off posts with "thanks" and "best" and the like.  Please do not sign off with your name and initial.  The site norm, as you can see in the vast majority of posts, is not to do so.

Comment: ok thx will do so from now on.